# CM_Register_Notification returning CR_IVALID_DATA (Error code 31)

Tags: go

I am trying to implement Windows 10 [CM_Register_Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_register_notification) in Golang. I don't now why this code is returning error 31.
**I don't want to use RegisterDeviceNotification**.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    cfgmgr32               = syscall.NewLazyDLL("cfgmgr32.dll")
    cmRegisterNotification = cfgmgr32.NewProc("CM_Register_Notification")
)

type CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE uint32

const (
    CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEHANDLE    CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE = 0x00000000
    CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINSTANCE  CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE = 0x00000001
    CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINTERFACE CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE = 0x00000002
)

type FILTER_FLAGS uint32

const (
    None                                        FILTER_FLAGS = 0
    CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES FILTER_FLAGS = 0x00000001
    CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_DEVICE_INSTANCES  FILTER_FLAGS = 0x00000002
)

type CM_NOTIFY_FILTER struct {
    cbSize     uint32
    Flags      FILTER_FLAGS
    FilterType CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE
    Reserved   uint32
    u          struct {
        DeviceInterface struct {
            ClassGuid syscall.GUID
        }
        DeviceHandle struct {
            hTarget syscall.Handle
        }
        DeviceInstance struct {
            InstanceId [200]uint16
        }
    }
}

type HCMNOTIFICATION uintptr

type CM_NOTIFY_ACTION uint32

type PCM_NOTIFY_EVENT_DATA uintptr

type PCM_NOTIFY_CALLBACK func(hNotify HCMNOTIFICATION, context unsafe.Pointer, action CM_NOTIFY_ACTION, eventData PCM_NOTIFY_EVENT_DATA, eventDataSize uint32) uintptr

func main() {
    filter := &CM_NOTIFY_FILTER{
        cbSize:     uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(CM_NOTIFY_FILTER{})),
        FilterType: CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_TYPE_DEVICEINTERFACE,
        Flags:      CM_NOTIFY_FILTER_FLAG_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES,
        Reserved:   0,
        u: struct {
            DeviceInterface struct {
                ClassGuid syscall.GUID
            }
            DeviceHandle struct {
                hTarget syscall.Handle
            }
            DeviceInstance struct {
                InstanceId [200]uint16
            }
        }{
            DeviceInterface: struct{ ClassGuid syscall.GUID }{
                ClassGuid: syscall.GUID{Data1: 0x4d36e96c, Data2: 0xe325, Data3: 0x11ce, Data4: [8]byte{0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18}},
            },
        },
    }

    var hNotify HCMNOTIFICATION

    ret, ret2, err := cmRegisterNotification.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(filter)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(nil)),
        syscall.NewCallback(PCM_NOTIFY_CALLBACK(NotifyCallback)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&hNotify)),
    )

    if ret != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Falha ao registrar notificação")
        fmt.Println("Falha ao registrar notificação", ret)
        fmt.Println("Falha ao registrar notificação", ret2)
        fmt.Println("Falha ao registrar notificação", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Notificação registrada com sucesso")
}

func NotifyCallback(hNotify HCMNOTIFICATION, context unsafe.Pointer, action CM_NOTIFY_ACTION, eventData PCM_NOTIFY_EVENT_DATA, eventDataSize uint32) uintptr {
    switch action {
    case 0:
        fmt.Println("Dispositivo de interface conectado")
    case 1:
        fmt.Println("Dispositivo de interface removido")
    default:
        fmt.Printf("Evento desconhecido: %d\n", action)
    }

    return 0
}
```

I expect to receive return code 0. I am using a valid combination of [CM_NOTIFY_FILTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/ns-cfgmgr32-cm_notify_filter) , but this just don't work. I have tried almost all possible combinations, but the error remains.